# How can i return a value from parent function after child function completed

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm implementing a simple validation function, which should return `true/false` depends on image size.
The inner `img.onload` function takes some time to execute, so parent `checkImagesWidth` should wait for it's completion.

Here is the code:

```
checkImagesWidth: function (file, restrictions) {
  var img = new Image()
  img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file)
  img.onload = () => {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src)
    return (img.naturalWidth >= restrictions.width) || (img.naturalHeight >= restrictions.height)
  }
}
```

In another words, the idea is to get `true/false` after `checkImagesWidth()` and use this value inside `if` statement like a regular `true/false` value.

I was trying to implement this approach via callbacks, promises, async/await, but no success.
Is this even possible?

Comment: try:
`return img.onload = () => ...`
or you can add assign the T/F value to a variable inside the function and return it after the img.onload execution

Comment: @MaxSvid that will not work at all.

Comment: @MaxSvid it will not work. ad is event which will execute only when the image is loaded and hence checkImagesWidth will execute and exit before onload executes.

Comment: @MaxSvid I was trying this as well. It just returns a function's (img.onload) code.

Comment: so you can transform the function to be async and use async/await syntax or modify the function abit:
`let y = null;
  img.onload = () => {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src)
    y = (img.naturalWidth >= restrictions.width) || (img.naturalHeight >= restrictions.height)
  }

return y`

Comment: @MaxSvid please don't answer in comments. If you have an answer, use the answer box for that.

Answer (score 1):

onload is event which will execute only when the image is loaded and hence checkImagesWidth will execute and exit before onload executes. Its better if you could explain why you need true/false to return would help structure it properly.

There are few ways to do what you want to do here

First is call back to function

```
function callback(boolValue) {
  // do something with it
}

checkImagesWidth: function (file, restrictions, callback) {
  var img = new Image()
  img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file)
  img.onload = () => {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src)
    callback(img.naturalWidth >= restrictions.width) || (img.naturalHeight >= restrictions.height)
  }
}
```

second could be promise

```
checkImagesWidth: function (file, restrictions, callback) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var img = new Image()
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file)
    img.onload = () => {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src)
      if((img.naturalWidth >= restrictions.width) || (img.naturalHeight >= restrictions.height)){
        resolve(true)
      }else {
        reject(false)
      }
    }
  });
}

consumer: function() {
  checkImagesWidth().then(()=>{
    // when it true do something
  }).catch(()=>{
    //false case
  })

}
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I've updated the post and added explanation about "why i need true/false".

Comment: @Andrew as explained earlier its not possible to check true/false returned from checkImagesWidth function as it contains code that executes later you will have to use promise or callback

Comment: Yes. That is what i expected. :)
Anyway, thank you for your explanation.